# .NET Library for Converting MS Publisher Files to PDF?

Tags: .net, pdf, ms-publisher

I have a client who saves a lot of newsletters in Microsoft Publisher 2007.  They want to be able to archive these in pdf format on a website which I'm building.  Aside from having them be forced to export the file to pdf from Publisher then upload it to our site for archival, is there any library out there that can help me convert Publisher files into PDFs?  This way the user could simply upload the Publisher file to the site and I could convert it on the server then archive it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack, but if you install Primo PDF, you can then save anything as a PDF by printing it and choosing the (virtual) Primo PDF printer that will now appear on the list of printers. Should be easy to access this via code as you are basically printing the Publisher document (but would require an instance of Publisher on your site).

Answer (score 0):

Publisher can save to post script